# objc_getAssociatedObject returns the wrong value

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, associated-object

Below is the code to associate an extra value with a button

```
- (int)uniqueId
{
    return (int)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, uniqueIdStringKeyConstant);
}

- (void)setUniqueId:(int)uniqueId
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, uniqueIdStringKeyConstant, [NSNumber numberWithInt:uniqueId], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}
```

When I try to fetch the value of `uniqueId` it returns the wrong value.

```
[button1 setUniqueId:1];
NSLog(@"%d",[button1 uniqueId]); // in console it prints 18
```

Can any one please help me to find out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting an `NSNumber` directly to an `int`, which will return you the value of the pointer address of the object.

What you wanted to do was:

```
return [(NSNumber *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, uniqueIdStringKeyConstant) intValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

You're storing an `NSNumber`, and then casting it to `int`. You can't do that - casting doesn't change the data type.

Try this:

```
- (int)uniqueId
{
    NSNumber *number = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, uniqueIdStringKeyConstant);
    return number.intValue;
}
```